# Не работает кодеровка utf-8

Tags: php, curl, utf-8, кодировка

Всем привет. Помогите решить проблему.
Через curl получаю страницу, в ответе headers кодировка windows-1251, в meta теге кодировка utf-8, скрипт в который отправляет запрос в utf-8. В ответ получаю (ïîëíîå ðóêîâîäñòâî, êëàññè÷åñêîå èçäàíèå - Ãåðáåðò Øèëäò)
С использование функции mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'windows-1251'); ответ (ГЇГ®Г«Г­Г®ГҐ Г°ГіГЄГ®ГўГ®Г¤Г±ГІГўГ®, ГЄГ«Г Г±Г±ГЁГ·ГҐГ±ГЄГ®ГҐ ГЁГ§Г¤Г Г­ГЁГҐ - ГѓГҐГ°ГЎГҐГ°ГІ Г?ГЁГ«Г¤ГІ)

```
$multi_curl = new MultiCurl();
$multi_curl->setConnectTimeout(300);
$multi_curl->setTimeout(300);
$multi_curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$multi_curl->setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7");
$multi_curl->success(function($instance) use($competitor) {

    $sql_insert = [];
    $pq = phpQuery::newDocument($instance->response);

    $name = trim($pq->find('h1.name')->text()); 

    $pq->unloadDocument();
});

foreach ($source_links as $value) {
   $multi_curl->addGet($value['url']);
}

$multi_curl->start();
```

Comment: Вам доступен сервер который отвечает? Есть возможность его настроить?

Comment: нет, я делаю парсер инофы с разных сайтов.